# How to query PostgreSQL database table from Access?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access-2007

I am very new to SQL, MS Access & PostgreSQL. So this might be a very silly question but somehow I can't figure it out. I'm trying to run SQL queries in access and my data is in a PostgreSQL database table which was linked to access by my colleague earlier. When I make this simple query why do I get an error that the table doesn't exist? Is the syntax different for linked database tables? Or is the link not yet established?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a **Pass-Through query**. This query is executed on the server, not in Access, so you need to use the original table names from the PostgreSQL database.

So it's not `FROM public_tb_change` but `FROM tb_change`.

Or maybe `FROM public.tb_change`, if `public` isn't the default schema.

I advise to rename your linked tables to the original name (remove `public_`), that makes things much less confusing. The schema name is automatically added by Access when linking the tables.

Comment: Removing 'public' from the table name and redoing the query with that new table name did the trick. Thanks!